# Powershell search for file with name -like and then copy to location

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

Have a script which search a given network location for specific file based on a given word. I need to adapt this and get the script to copy the file to another given network location.

Can someone help?

```
"`n" 
write-Host "Search Running" -ForegroundColor Red
$filePath = "\\fileserver\mylocation$\folder"
"`n" 

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and  ( $_.Name -like "*keyword*" 
 ) } | Select-Object Name,Directory,CreationTime,LastAccessTime,LastWriteTime | Export-Csv "C:\scripts\searches\csv\27022014.csv" -notype
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, or done any research (like running get-help move-item)

Comment: I thought I could use that but with being a bit of a noob to PS I am unsure how I can add this part into my current script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spend some time looking at the documentation on `Copy-Item`.  Run `man copy-item -full` at the prompt.  Look at the examples at the bottom on the help.

Then modify your script to something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and  ($_.Name -like "*keyword*") } |
    Copy-Item -Dest \\fileserver2\difflocation
```

Comment: Thanks, figured the rest. Much appreciated.